# Uploading a document for a site not created yet

Tags: 2013

I have a form which creates a project management site for user, user wants to uploads a document by uploading it to project management new site form.

What can i do to upload a document to a site not created yet but will be created soon using asynch event.

My problem is I doesnot know where to keep document until my asynch code creates site and come back to get the document, should I create a temporary library on root web, or store it in sql blob cache or on local network disk space.

Comment: What are you using to develop this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upload a document to a site which is not yet created.
You can use SPWebEventReceiver.WebProvisioned event to upload your document as this is Synchronous After event that fires after a subsite is fully provisioned and the provisioning process has stopped, **but does not fire when the root web site of a new site collection is created**.

http://sharepointtrac.wordpress.com/2013/11/27/site-provisioning-with-an-attached-event-receiver/

Comment: Thank You But Where the document will be stored

Comment: You can use your local drive or shared location and after uploading you can delete that.

Comment: SQL blob cache is also a good option.

Comment: can you also give me reason why one option is good then other as thats i am asking

Comment: You can use a shared location to store the document as it would be easier for you to retrieve  document from that location. Other you need to write extra code for making connection etc.